# How to save and load a dictionary of scipy sparse csr matrices?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a `dict` of `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` objects as values, with integer keys. How can I save this in a separate file?

If I had a regular `ndarray` for each entry, then I could serialize it with `json`, but when I try this with a sparse matrix:

```
    with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(the_matrix))
```

I get a TypeError:

`TypeError: <75x75 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format> is not JSON serializable`

How can I save my dictionary with keys that are integers and values that are sparse csr matrices?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue trying to save a dictionary whose values are csr_matrix. Dumped it to disk using pickle. file handler should be opened in "wb" mode.

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(csr_dict_obj, open("csr_dict.pkl","wb"))
```

load the dict back using.

```
csr_dict = pickle.load(open("csr_dict.pkl","rb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer `scipy` versions have a `scipy.sparse.save_npz` function (and corresponding load).  It saves the attributes of a sparse matrix to a `numpy` `savez` zip archive. In the case of a `csr` is saves the `data`, `indices` and `indptr` arrays, plus shape.

`scipy.io.savemat` can save a sparse matrix in a MATLAB compatible format (csc).  There are one or two other `scipy.io` formats that can handle sparse matrices, but I haven't worked with them.

While a sparse matrix contains numpy arrays it isn't an array subclass, so the `numpy` functions can't be used directly.

The `pickle` method for numpy arrays is its `np.save`.  And an array that contains objects, uses `pickle` (if possible).  So a pickle of a dictionary of arrays should work.

The sparse `dok` format is a subclass of `dict`, so might be pickleable.  It might even work with `json`.  But I haven't tried it.

By the way, a plain numpy array can't be `jsoned` either:

```
In [427]: json.dumps(np.arange(5))
TypeError: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) is not JSON serializable
In [428]: json.dumps(np.arange(5).tolist())
Out[428]: '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

`dok` doesn't work either.  The keys are tuples of indices,

```
In [433]: json.dumps(M.todok())
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

`MatrixMarket` is a text format that handles sparse:

```
In [444]: io.mmwrite('test.mm', M)   
In [446]: cat test.mm.mtx
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate integer general
%
1 5 4
1 2 1
1 3 2
1 4 3
1 5 4
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, but when I was referring to the `json` serializable object, I was referring to the `dict`, which is serializable. A `dict` of numpy arrays can be serialized. A `dict` of scipy sparse csr matrices cannot. I'm looking for a way to save a `dict` where the keys are integers and the values are scipy sparse csr matrices,

Comment: To serialize a dictionary you have to be able to serialize all of its values - that is, the serialization has to be defined for each component object.

Comment: Okay, let's leave serialization alone then, since sparse matrices are not serializable. How can I save a dict whose values are non-serializable?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix, csr_matrix, issparse
import re
def save_sparse_csr(filename, **kwargs):
    arg_dict = dict()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if issparse(value):
            value = value.tocsr()
            arg_dict[key+'_data'] = value.data
            arg_dict[key+'_indices'] = value.indices
            arg_dict[key+'_indptr'] = value.indptr
            arg_dict[key+'_shape'] = value.shape
        else:
            arg_dict[key] = value

    np.savez(filename, **arg_dict)

def load_sparse_csr(filename):
    loader = np.load(filename)
    new_d = dict()
    finished_sparse_list = []
    sparse_postfix = ['_data', '_indices', '_indptr', '_shape']

    for key, value in loader.items():
        IS_SPARSE = False
        for postfix in sparse_postfix:
            if key.endswith(postfix):
                IS_SPARSE = True
                key_original = re.match('(.*)'+postfix, key).group(1)
                if key_original not in finished_sparse_list:
                    value_original = csr_matrix((loader[key_original+'_data'], loader[key_original+'_indices'], loader[key_original+'_indptr']),
                                      shape=loader[key_original+'_shape'])
                    new_d[key_original] = value_original.tolil()
                    finished_sparse_list.append(key_original)
                break

        if not IS_SPARSE:
            new_d[key] = value

    return new_d
```

You can write a wrapper as shown above.