# How to save a dictionary of scipy sparse csr matrices?

Tags: python, scipy

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625864/how-to-save-and-load-a-dictionary-of-scipy-sparse-csr-matrices), but I'm having trouble with using `save_npz`.

I have a dictionary of scipy sparse csr matrices called `adj_mat_time_t`.

I'm trying to save it to a file via:

`scipy.sparse.save_npz('binary_adj_mats.npz', adj_mat_time_t)`

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
  File "my_prog.py", line 400...
    scipy.sparse.save_npz('binary_adj_mats.npz', adj_mat_time_t)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_matrix_io.py", line 64, in save_npz
    arrays_dict = dict(format=matrix.format.encode('ascii'),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
```

I'm working with scipy version 1.0.0

How can I fix this?

Comment: `save_npz` is designed to work with a single sparse matrix.  It does not handle a list or dictionary of matrices.  You'll have to do your own iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay. Would you be willing to code up an example as a solution?

Comment: That's basic Python file and dictionary operations.

Comment: Okay, but dictionaries aren't serializable as far as I know, so `json` isn't a solution. Should I try to pickle this?

Comment: What I mean is that if you are going to use `save_npz` you have write each matrix to a separate file.  You could alternatively try the MATLAB format, `savemat`.

Comment: Ooh, that would mean more than 12,000 files! Not an option, I'm afraid. According to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232751/saving-and-loading-python-dict-with-savemat-results-in-error), `savemat` does not preserve the nature of a dictionary. Any other ideas?

Comment: why not just pickle this dictionary?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks guys.